# How do I use CSS to select a "cousin" element

Tags: html, css, madcap

I have the following (simplified) HTML

```
<ul class="sidenav">
    <li class="tree-node">
        <a href="url">
            <span class="submenu-toggle-container">Text</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="accordion-menu">
            <li class="HideMenu">.......</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="tree-node">...</li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to use CSS to hide the `.submenu-toggle-container` span when the sibling is `ul li.HideMenu`.

I have been able to make this work using jQuery code
`$('ul.sidenav li.HideMenu').parent('ul').siblings('a').children('.submenu-toggle-container').hide();` but this is not optimal for my project and I would much rather use CSS to make this work.

My attempts include

```
ul.sidenav li.HideMenu ~ ul a .submenu-toggle-container {
  display: none;
}
```

but this does not work.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `:has`

```css
a:has(+ ul.accordion-menu li.HideMenu) .submenu-toggle-container {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="sidenav">
  <li class="tree-node">
    <a href="url">
      <span class="submenu-toggle-container">Text</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="accordion-menu">
      <li class="HideMenu">.......</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="tree-node">...</li>
</ul>
```

Does not supported by firefox if `layout.css.has-selector.enabled` is fasle.

[image]

Comment: Thanks heaps (and to the other answers too). I played around with the :has selector but couldn't get the syntax right.

Answer (score 1):

[Shuo beat me to it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76469673/636077) but you could pull this off with the [:has selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has):

```css
/*
  select .submenu-toggle-container children of
  .tree-node that has a li.HideMenu child
*/
.tree-node:has(ul li.HideMenu) .submenu-toggle-container {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="sidenav">
    <li class="tree-node">
        <a href="url">
            <span class="submenu-toggle-container">Text</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="accordion-menu">
            <li class="HideMenu">.......</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="tree-node">...</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [first answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76469673/21148174) by Shuo is the same as mine, but I'll leave this here in case anyone wants to read more into how this solution works.

This can be accomplished through the use of the recent [:has()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) psuedo-class.

Here's a quick bit of CSS to show how it can work:

```css
li.tree-node a:has(+ ul.accordion-menu li.HideMenu) .submenu-toggle-container {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="sidenav">
    <li class="tree-node">
        <a href="url">
            <span class="submenu-toggle-container">Hide Me</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="accordion-menu">
            <li class="HideMenu">Hide Menu</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="tree-node">...</li>
</ul>
```

I used `background: red;` because it's easier to show something than to not show something, so you'd just need to replace that with `display: none;`

So, how does it work?

To start, we cannot select a parent in CSS, so we need to work through siblings. This means that the route to the `.HideMenu` element has to be from the `a` to its sibling `ul` and then the `li`. This is why we write the `a:has(+ ul.accordion-menu li.HideMenu)` selector.

With the above, we've established the relationship through the sibling to the desired element to toggle your submenu. All that's needed is to write the next selector to target that specific decendant.

Great? Right! Well, beware -- **there is a catch: this solution is not supported in Firefox.**

To be able to do this same thing in Firefox, you will need to write JS/JQuery code to add support for this feature yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information about :has